# How to pass parameters for BackgroundService?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I read about ASP.net core 2.2 and I found reference about generic host.

I tried to create console app with backgroundService under example: https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore.Docs/tree/master/aspnetcore/fundamentals/host/generic-host/samples/

```
var param = Console.ReadLine();

var host = new HostBuilder().ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
{
   services.AddHostedService<MyCustomSerivce>();
}
```

The problem is how can be passed argument from command line (in my case 'param'), that will specified internal logic in particular background service.

Comment: At a high level, you should use the built-in configuration system and add the command line params to the config. The service can then get configuration objects through DI.

Answer (score 10):

For resolving service, you need to register the parameters into service collection.

1. Service for storing the parameter

   ```
   public class CommandLineArgs
   {
       public string Args { get; set; }
   }
   ```
2. Register the parameter

   ```
   public class Program
   {
       public static async Task Main(string[] args)
       {
           var param = Console.ReadLine();

           var host = new HostBuilder()
               .ConfigureHostConfiguration(configHost =>
               {
                   configHost.SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory());
                   configHost.AddJsonFile("hostsettings.json", optional: true);
                   configHost.AddEnvironmentVariables(prefix: "PREFIX_");
                   configHost.AddCommandLine(args);
               })
               .ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostContext, configApp) =>
               {
                   configApp.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true);
                   configApp.AddJsonFile(
                       $"appsettings.{hostContext.HostingEnvironment.EnvironmentName}.json", 
                       optional: true);
                   configApp.AddEnvironmentVariables(prefix: "PREFIX_");
                   configApp.AddCommandLine(args);
               })
               .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
               {
                   services.AddSingleton(new CommandLineArgs { Args = param });
                   services.AddHostedService<LifetimeEventsHostedService>();
                   services.AddHostedService<TimedHostedService>();
               })
               .ConfigureLogging((hostContext, configLogging) =>
               {
                   configLogging.AddConsole();
                   configLogging.AddDebug();
               })
               .UseConsoleLifetime()
               .Build();

           await host.RunAsync();
       }
   }
   ```
3. Resolve service

   ```
   internal class TimedHostedService : IHostedService, IDisposable
   {
       private readonly ILogger _logger;
       private Timer _timer;
       private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;
       private readonly CommandLineArgs _commandLineArgs;
       public TimedHostedService(ILogger<TimedHostedService> logger
           , IConfiguration configuration
           , CommandLineArgs commandLineArgs)
       {
           _logger = logger;
           _configuration = configuration;
           _commandLineArgs = commandLineArgs;
       }       
   }
   ```

Comment: What's the point of having `configApp.AddCommandLine(args)` here?

Comment: I am not sure if TimedHostedService will start at all

Comment: To @ElMac question, It will be part of the IConfiguration instance and if we are having our own model for the config file(s), then even this named args will get resolved to the respective prop with value. say, we use like `appName.exe --Param1 "Value1"` it will resolve to the Binding model as long as they have the `public string Param1 {get; set;}` as one of the property.